# How to use Lists in ASP NET Framework with the POST method?

Tags: model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, frameworks

I have the following Model in my ASP NET Framework project:

```
public class User
    {
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "El formato del correo electrónico no es válido.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe de introducir un Correo Electrónico.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

And there is the controller methods:

```
public ActionResult AddUsers()
        {

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddUsers(List<User> users)
        {
            //Do something with users

            return View();
        }
```

In the form I want a List of the User Model that I mentioned above to be collected. When loading the view it is not known how many Users there will be. This will be indicated in a numeric type input and dynamically it will have to generate as many entries for Email as indicated in the numeric input. When the form is submitted I would like a List of Users to be submitted.

How can I dynamically generate inputs for the User model and have it saved in a list and then sent to the controller?

I expect my controller to receive a list of Users picked up from the form

Comment: Can you explain about `This will be indicated in a numeric type input`? Do you mean when the view load, There will be two kinds of input in the view, The first type of input will show the count of list of user and the second type of input will show each user email or just generate as many new input tag as the List of the User Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I think when the page load, It will generate a input to show the count of `list<User>` and it will also generate as many input tag as the count of `list<User>`, So I create a simple demo to achieve it, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

```
public IActionResult AddUsers()
        {
            //for testing, i hard code herer
            List<User> users = new List<User>()
            {
                new User()
                {
                    Email = "123456@gmail.com"
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Email = "abcdef@gmail.com"
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Email = "111111@gmail.com"
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Email = "987654321@gmail.com"
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Email = "555555@gmail.com"
                }
            };
            return View(users);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model List<User>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUsers", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="number" value="@Model.Count" disabled/>
    <br/>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <input name="User[@i].Email" value="@Model[i].Email"/>
        <br />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**When the view load, It will generate like:**

[image]

Then when you submit the form, it can receive the data of `list<user>`

[image]